# Continuous Integration and Salesforce Metadata

Tags: metadata, continuous-integration, ci

I am trying to find a Continuous Integration solution not only for Apex code, Visualforce and Lightning Component but also for other Metadata.

For example, I would check if on a Remote Site the Admin has checked "Disable Protocol Security".

Is it possible or not?
Thanks!

Comment: You can get along with Salesforce Metadata CI or Get started with salesforce DX. They both work and are amazing. The downside is the steep learning curve and months spent in getting it to work according to your org, If spending few bucks is not an issue I would recommend buying a product like gearset or autorabbit etc . The time and money spend on devs reinventing the well  can be well spent on designing SF systems and not on designing deployment tools,

Answer (score 4):

As long as a component is available as a Metadata component, you can utilize that in any Continuous Integration solution. It’s not restricted to only apex or lightning component. You can deploy workflow rules, profiles, permission sets, named credentials, etc. to name a few.

On top of this, you should definitely explore Salesforce DX if you are starting towards building a CI solution. Few good places to start will be:

- [Salesforce DX Developer Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_setup.meta/sfdx_setup/sfdx_setup_intro.htm)
- [Continuous Integration Using Salesforce DX](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/sfdx_travis_ci)